How to Efficiently Read Large Datasets from Firestore with Reduced Latency?
I’m working on a project that requires fetching large datasets from Firestore to display patient data. The data is structured as follows: patients/daily(collection)//document, where each document contains summary and samples fields. My goal is to read this data efficiently to display it in my application.
Problem:
Regardless of the approach I take, fetching data for significant intervals (e.g., the last 2 years, 3 months intervals going back 2 years, or combinations like 3m, 3m, 6m, 1y), the operations consistently take over 30 seconds, which is far from optimal. I’m seeking a method to significantly reduce this latency.
What I’ve Tried:

Fetching the Last 2 Years Directly: Attempted to fetch the entire dataset for the last two years in one go.
Interval Fetching: Tried fetching data in intervals (3m, 3m, 6m, 1y) sequentially.
Batch Processing: Considered batch processing but unsure how to implement it effectively in Firestore.

Questions:

Are there any Firestore-specific strategies or optimizations for reading large datasets that I might be overlooking?
Is there a more efficient way to structure my database or queries to improve read performance?
Could Firestore’s local caching capabilities be leveraged to improve subsequent read operations’ latency?

const collectionRef = collection(db, "patients", id, "daily");

const startDateStr = startDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
 
const q = query(
  collectionRef,
  where("start_time", ">=", startDateStr),
  where("start_time", "<", endDateStr)
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

After this i go over every snapshot to retrieve the summary and samples into 2 different arrays one for the summary and one for the samples.
I expected that by breaking down the fetch operations into smaller intervals or by batching, I could reduce the overall latency. However, none of these methods have reduced the fetch time to under 30 seconds.
Document Count and Data Volume: Each query retrieves 556 documents, with the total data size amounting to approximately 110.6 MB. There is so many data we don't use in the documents and we are considering moving these documents to a collection that only have for exemple the Summarey/Samples.
Network Bandwidth: (97.84) Mbps download speed as measured by Speedtest.net.
It takes between 35 - 45 seconds to load the data.

The time it takes to load data is gonna be linear to the amount of data that you're loading. So: how many documents are you loading? How much data is in them? How much time does it take? What type of network/bandwidth are you testing on? --- The next question is going to be: do you really need that many individual documents? Or are you just loading those document to show aggregated data to the user? And if the latter, consider storing the aggregated data in one (or a few) document and load it from there.

@FrankvanPuffelen I have now updated the question with the required data.
I must mention that every document we fetch has all the data. So in one fetch we get only the Samples and summary, but the other data like distance, rate etc. are present in the same document. That's why we are considering if it will reduce the time if we move every data to a seperate collection.

A general principle I follow when modeling data for a NoSQL database is to try and only retrieve data that the app immediately displays to the data.
You say that you retrieve 556 documents, which seems a lot of documents to display completely to the user - and you already acknowledge that a lot of the data in those documents is not displayed to the user. So why would you retrieve that data?
The solution in NoSQL databases is almost always the same: modify your data model for the use-case you have. So in the above use-case, take the data that you actually use from each documents, and store that data in one new document, or in a new collection with a small number of documents. Then load that new document or the new collection, instead of reading the 556 individual documents.
This means you'll potentially need to write the same data to multiple places in the database, which will complicate your write operation and goes against best practices you probably know from working with relational databases. But when dealing with NoSQL databases, these practices are actually completely normal. In NosQL we often end up complicating write operations to get faster, simpler, more scalable read operations.
To learn more about this, I recommend reading NoSQL data modeling and watching Get to know Cloud Firestore.
